# Strange outcome with Enumerate .inject in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello guys I just encountered something strange with inject in Ruby.

```
(1..6).inject(1) { |sum, c| puts c % 2 == 0 ? c + 1 : c * 2 }
```

Output:

```
2
3
6
5
10
7
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
2
3
6
7
14
15
```

Why is this subtracting 1 and 3 instead of adding 1?

Comment: You should use `#each` instead of `#inject`.

Comment: I need the sum at the end. puts is just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is correct:

```
1 * 2 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 * 2 = 6
4 + 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
6 + 1 = 7
```